# IQ questions - Can you solve them?

Tags: pattern

Can you answer and explain the logic behind these questions?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Source: https://similarminds.com/cgi-bin/int.pl

Comment: Can you please reference the source of this IQ test!

Comment: The first one is rot13(o rnpu qvntenz unf gur fnzr ahzore bs rnpu flzoby). The third one is an easier version of the same puzzle.

Comment: Sorry. I am new to this forum. I got these questions from the site:

Comment: https://similarminds.com/cgi-bin/int.pl

Comment: I get a blank screen for the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First one:

> B. Each image contains two crosses, three squares, two triangles and two circles.

Second one:

> D. The lines in the middle rotate 45 degrees anti clockwise. Upper left rotates 45 degrees clockwise. Upper right 90 degrees. Lower left 45 degrees anti clockwise, then 90 degrees, then 180 and thus finally 360. Lower right 45 degrees clockwise.

Third one:

> D. one of each figure.

Fourth one:

> A. In each step, two figures remain the same while two change in this way: triangle -> square -> circle -> triangle. In the first step, the two lower figures (square and triangle) change, in next step the two on the diagonal running from lower left to upper right figure change, and thus in third step the two in the diagonal running from lower right to upper left change.

Answer (score 0):

> The Answers are b,d,b,d,a. In the first one, that is the only answer with the same construction as the other three shapes: 3 squares, 2 circles, 2 triangles, two crosses. Second is top left rotates clockwise 45 degrees each from one shape to the next and same for the middle and bottom right, top right fluctuates back and forth between the two shapes and bottom right has stopped changing after the third shape. Third one it is the only answer with the construction of top left and bottom right combined. Top left is the bigger shape, bottom right is in the middle. Fourth, it is the only answer with the construction of four different shapes put together. Last one is because the two similar shapes in the column alternates columns and then changes shape. Also the other two shapes cannot be the same as the shape in the column just mentioned.

Comment: For 2, bottom left rotates 45,90,180,360,720,1440 gives (d). But (e) - period 4 - works too.

Comment: What do you mean by period 4?

Comment: BL goes =, //, \\, \\, =, //, \\, \\, … repeating every four, in tune with the other 4 shapes. (based on some of the other questions in this test this seems reasonable enough!)

Comment: Yo no upvote 

Comment: Great answers, Deepthink. I agree with you. The one I had more difficult was #2. I agree with JMP that answer (e) was also reasonable. You guys are very smart. Thank you very much. I have few more questions that are intriguing. I will post them soon.